# Python version of the system - conflicts with python 2.4 binary and add debian lenny repositories

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.4

```
dpkg -i python-zopeinterface_3.3.1-7_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 68426 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python-zopeinterface_3.3.1-7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-zopeinterface (3.3.1-7) over (3.3.1-7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-zopeinterface:
 python-zopeinterface depends on python (<< 2.6); however:
  Version of python on system is 2.7.16-1.
 python-zopeinterface depends on python-central (>= 0.6.6); however:
  Package python-central is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python-zopeinterface (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-zopeinterface
```

I don't understand why I have the message "Version of python on system is 2.7.16-1." whereas when I do :

```
$ python
Python 2.4.4 (#2, Jan 24 2010, 11:50:13)
[GCC 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So python binary is 2.4 version.

I have forced python2.4 to be current python :

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.4 1
```

How t indicate that python version of the system is python2.4 ? to be able to install  `python-zopeinterface_3.3.1-7_amd64.deb`.

### Edit

I tried to add repositories of `lenny` by setting into `sources.list` :

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free #Added by software-properties

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main non-free contrib
```

But once I do an `apt-get update`, I get the following key error :

```
Ign:1 http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release [99.6 kB]
Hit:4 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release [92.4 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release.gpg [1034 B]
Get:7 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release.gpg [836 B]
Ign:6 http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release.gpg
Ign:7 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG AED4B06F473041FA Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org> 9FED2BCBDCD29CDF762678CBAED4B06F473041FA EXPKEYSIG 4D270D06F42584E6 Lenny Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org> 7F5A44454C724A65CBCD4FB14D270D06F42584E6
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 9AA38DCD55BE302B Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (5.0/lenny) <ftpmaster@debian.org> 150C8614919D8446E01E83AF9AA38DCD55BE302B
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How to find a workaround to add `lenny` repositores to be signed ?

Comment: Note that both of those Python versions are _extremely_ out of date, so the best course of action is probably something that involves upgrading to use a newer version of Python - at least 3.7, as of when I write this. (If that's what you're trying to do here, then please carry on.)

Comment: Why are you running an _extremely_ old version of Debian in the first place anyway? There will be a number of security problems in there which are never going to be fixed.

Comment: I want to use this since I am running a zope3 server and I have not the time to migrate to earlier versions. Everything was working fine up to now on my VPS but i did a mistake during an upgrade tthat has broken my zope3 installation, it is very frustrating. zope3 instance is not compatible with zope2 or zope > 3. Best regards